# Linux. Heroku-Django. Collectstatic read-only file system

Tags: python, linux, django, heroku, chmod

I need help from someone who understands linux. I can't push my staticfiles to Heroku (I'm trying to use whitenoise and not Amazon S3 or any CDN). The error is rather simple, when I try to push to heroku I get:

```
 Preparing static assets
       Running collectstatic...
       Traceback (most recent call last):
       OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/assets'
```

So, I can't run collectstatic cause I don't have permissions. If I do `sudo git push heroku master` I get another error: `Permission denied (publickey)` And I guess that is cause 'sudo' uses a different SSH key.

I've tried to change permissions to the folder from the file manager and I've also tried from bash:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R static
```

static is the parent folder: static/assets.

So... how can I solve this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the problem is pushing content to Heroku, specifically. You're trying to save assets to a root folder on the virtual machine, which your'e not allowed to do.

Traditionally with Heroku, you'd set the static assets directory to something like `staticfiles` (not `/staticfiles` or `/assets`). When Heroku deploys the app to its virtual machines (what it calls "dynos") it works in its own little directory (I think it's `/app`), so all the directories you specify in your settings.py file are relative to that directory.

Try setting the static files root directory to `staticfiles` or `assets` without the slash, and that should work.